# Remove all items other then the first one from a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Title says it all - how do remove all of the items, other then the first one, from a stackpanel? Clear() just remove them all and won't work in this case. RemoveAt() doesn't really help. There is no set amount of items that will be in the stackpanel at any given time.

Comment: so `while(TitlePanel.Children.Count > 1){ TitlePanel.Children.RemoveAt(1); }`  -- won't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
panel.Children.RemoveRange(1, panel.Children.Count - 1);
```

See the `RemoveRange` function ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.removerange(v=vs.110).aspx)).

The above code removes all children from the second item to the count - 1 (since you wanted to keep the first element).

For Windows Phone 8, you don't get that function, so you'll need to do something like this:

```
//Reversed to avoid the collection mutation exception
foreach (UIElement item in panel.Children.Skip(1).Reverse())
    panel.Remove(item);
```

Not as "clever" but its short, and obvious what you are doing!

Comment: RemoveRange doesn't exist in WP8.

Comment: @Kevin I don't have a WP8 setup to test on at the moment, but my edit *should* work.